# Callback funtions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose we have

```
function first(){
  console.log(1);
}
function second(){
  console.log(2);
}
first();
second();
```

That will print

```
1
2
```

Now we put a timer inside the first() function.

```
function first(){
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
  }, 500 );
}
function second(){
  console.log(2);
}
first();
second();
```

Now this will give the opposite.

```
2
1
```

That's because Javascript is an event-driven language. My question is how to define a callback function in the above example, so as to wait  and print

```
1
2
```

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: Either pass the second function to the first and let it execute it as callback, or let the first function return a promise whose completion you can await.

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

You just call `second()` inside `first()`.

```js
function first() {
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1);
    second();
  }, 500);
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first();
```